# Mule: xml-stylesheet tag in Dataweave

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave

I should map a document to xml in Dataweave which has to contain

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="audit_stylesheet.xsl" ?>
```

after the Dataweave-made `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-15'?>` tag.

I was not able to avhieve this in dataweave because of the ? in the tag and especially the ending "?>".

Does anyone have a solution how i can finally achieve this in one Dataweave transformation:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-15'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
...
```

(My final solution would be some String Manipulating - but i would love to avoid this.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by DataWeave. If you really must associate an XLS stylesheet this way you will have to use a string replacement to do it. I agree it is not pretty. I wonder how many clients require this feature nowadays.